# How can I remove aliasing in an image without introducing blur?

Tags: image-processing, image, antialiasing, filtering

I am trying to reduce aliasing in an image using some filters. I tried the Gaussian variant of filters to remove the said high frequency patterns in the image, but I feel it's a bit too much of a blur.

I need a filter that can help me do some kind of anti-aliasing without doing too much blur.

I have searched a lot and unfortunately the results are not fruitful.

Comment: What are you requirements? Gaussian kernels are designed to blur without artifacts. A different kernel that blurs but isn't Gaussian is the box filter. It will produce artifacts however. I suppose more importantly, why isn't Gaussian good enough?

Comment: What kind of aliasing is present? Is it a synthetic image with staircasing/jaggies? Is it a texture with spurious low-frequency components (like a high-frequency grating or checkerboard)? Is it a photo that's been badly upscaled?

Comment: The image consist of Jaggies mostly ... like for instance, i have an image filled with Grass and I want to make sure that the grass blades are not too blurred.

Comment: a sinc filter can downsample "perfectly" such that any details that would cause aliasing are removed, while other details are left perfectly alone.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the specific content of your input images, you could either use the Gaussian filter with kernel size varying with distance from the camera ( [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing) ) or use a slightly more complex [bilateral filter](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/MANDUCHI1/Bilateral_Filtering.html), which is widely used to eliminate noise while keeping edges mostly intact.